# .Net Core Unit Test Issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, .net-core-1.1

I'm fairly new to .Net and I have an issue:

Setup is as follows: VS 2017, .Net Core (api project), .Net Core Unit test;

Api solution runs fine, test does not; it complains about:

```
Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Users\###_PC_NAME_###\Desktop\###_PROJECT_NAME_###\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\appsettings.json'.
```

Seems to me like the unit test wants a copy of the main project's appsettings.json file in it's own unit test project bin dir?!

Any thoughts you'd like to share with your new .NET Newbie :D ?

Comment: in solution explorer, in visual studio you should be able to set the properties of the file to always copy on build.

Comment: Thanks!! Seems to be working now.